# How to host a public WCF service?

Tags: c#, wcf

I'm trying to create a tcp wcf service that would be hosted on a server without IIS and that would be accessible to the public without authentication.

Here is what I do:

```
ServiceHost svh = new ServiceHost(typeof(MyService));

var tcpbinding = new NetTcpBinding(SecurityMode.None);

var location = "net.tcp://localhost:11111";
svh.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IMyService), tcpbinding, location);

svh.Open();
....
```

The service works fine on locashost, but when I set it up on the server (firewall exception added), the client crashes with a message:

```
The socket connection was aborted. This could be caused by an error processing 
your message or a receive timeout being exceeded by the remote host, or an 
underlying network resource issue. Local socket timeout was '00:00:59.7344663'.
```

Here's client configuration file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <startup> 
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
    </startup>
    <system.serviceModel>
        <bindings>
            <netTcpBinding>
                <binding name="NetTcpBinding_IMyService">
                    <security mode="None" />
                </binding>
            </netTcpBinding>
        </bindings>
        <client>
            <endpoint address="net.tcp://myserver:11111/"
                binding="netTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration="NetTcpBinding_IMyService"
                contract="MyServer.IMyService" name="NetTcpBinding_IMyService" />
        </client>
    </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

What should I change for this to work?

Comment: Did you read http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb332338.aspx ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar problem in the past and I solved it by not using `localhost` in the endpoint address (`ServiceHost` .ctor), but using the actual machine name instead. Also, you can define the address in the service host itself, as shown below.

```
ServiceHost svh = new ServiceHost(typeof(MyService), new Uri("net.tcp://myserver:11111"));
var tcpbinding = new NetTcpBinding(SecurityMode.None);
svh.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IMyService), tcpbinding, "");
svh.Open();
```